# CJK characters not displaying in Java 6 / RHEL 6

Tags: java, fonts

It seems that Chinese, Korean and Japanese characters can't be properly displayed on RHEL environments (instead, squares are displayed). I'm specifically testing with a Swing app, but it seems it is not limited to that.

I found this report by Red Hat saying it is simply not supported by Oracle - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=647157

But it seems very odd to me. This bug report - https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7010379 - seems to indicate a fix was included on jre 6u25, but that's the one I'm using, and it isn't there.

Is there anyone familiar with this issue, and if so, know any solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be fixed in SE 6u30 and SE 7. It seems like a problem with fontconfig files under jre/lib. The alternative seems to be using physical fonts instead, or simply upgrade.